# Mobx-Reactjs const {match: {params:{id}}} = props doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, parameters, mobx

I am working with Mobx and React. I want to get the id from de URL, from

```
const {match: {params:{id}}} = props
```

but it doesn't work. why?

Comment: Could you attach some more codes related to this?

Comment: I guess It's not about mobx, it's about react-router and @withRouter and this.props.history. But we don't have details :(